# Adding a border around .nav-tabs doubles up top border for .active class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've done a lot of research and can't come up with an elegant solution to this issue.

What I'd like is a border around my nav buttons so I do this:

```
.nav-tabs{border:1px solid #ddd;}
```

The problem is the active class appears to double up my top border (and my left border for the left-most tab). I try to undo it like this:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active{border-top-style:none;}
```

This removes the top border but then adds a bottom border.

I've seen the solutions for then setting the border bottom to the background color of the tab content while also maintaining a margin-bottom of -3px. But that is not working for me.

How can I add a border around my nav buttons without the .active state doubling them up?

Thanks for any helpful solutions.

Here's a link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43zzpvg2/

Comment: then we must see a demo....

Comment: Apologies, should have set that up first. The link is above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing what you've got, try this

```
.nav-tabs > li.active{border-top-color: transparent;}
```

In the past I've experienced the tabs moving when the border is removed.

I built something similar to what you're after [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/y97sb8fn/)

Comment: This gets me closer but now I see a 1px blank space between the side borders and the top border.

Comment: I actually built something similar to what you're after a few days ago. I've added a demo to my answer

Comment: Sorry about that. Try this link https://output.jsbin.com/muhice I'm still new to JS Bin

Comment: That bottom:-1px allows me to set the border-top-style to none without re-introducing the bottom border; very nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` like below

```
.nav-tabs .active {border-top: none!important}
```

Comment: That definitely works at getting rid of the top border but it still introduces the bottom one.